# How to fetch data from API which has multiple urls

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I have to fetch data from a backpage API which url is:

> http://sydney.backpage.com/online/api/Ad.xml

with an ajax jQuery request but my problem is that I want to fetch data not from only this URL but also

> http://brisbane.backpage.com/online/api/Ad.xml

perth and etc many more URLs.

So how can I fetch and and use it in my project?

Please help me guys I'm new at this.

Comment: Are you asking how you can fetch data with jQuery? Are you asking how you should manage all the subdomains? Are you asking how you get to know all possible subdomains?

Comment: Asking how you can fetch data with jQuery? That's why I add jQuery tag not Domail tag.

Comment: What is unclear with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/? You should come up with code and revisit SO if you have actual problems. SO is not there to provide you code (on the other hand there enough questions helping you out). Btw: If you are just talking about jQuery, than you might want to drop the php tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745885/how-to-send-ajax-request-to-multiple-urls here's code can you please check it?

Comment: You just have to make 2 calls, one for the fisrt subdomain, and one for the second.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a PHP question, but how to handle subdomains and DNS. To keep it short, let's say you go a server at a specific IP address. You need to go to your registrar and add DNS records to redirect each subdomains (sydney, brisbane, etc...) to this IP address. Next on your server, tell that you can handle those, and your PHP code will be called for each suddomain. Your PHP code can determine the subdomain used for the execution.

If you have to handle an unlimited subdomain list, you can use Nginx to proxy your server with * (meaning all) or a regular expression to include/exclude subdomains, and do a fallback redirection on your registrar DNS.

Comment: I'm asking using jQuery not domain, subdomain or IP.